# scala Try: closing a file in failure scenario

Tags: scala

I have written following code to write to a file:

```
Try {
       val filePath = "path/to/write/myfile.json"
       val file = new File(filePath)
       file.createNewFile();
       val fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)
       val objToWrite = someFunction()
       fileWriter.write(objToWrite.toJson)
       fileWriter.close()
     } match {
       case Failure(ex) =>
         log.error("Failed to save data")
         throw ex
       case Success(_) =>
         log.info("Data saved successfully")
    }
```

My question is does Try closes resource(file here) in case its a Failure?

If not, then how do we do it as finally block is not allowed with Try?

Also, can this IO operation be further improved as per scala best practises?

Comment: I really love that things like **cats-effect** / **ZIO** solve this an another million problems yet people don't use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *My question is does Try closes resource(file here) in case its a Failure?*

No. There's no resource management at all when using `Try`. It behaves like a "old school" Java `try..catch` *without* resource.

> *If not, then how do we do it as finally block is not allowed with Try?*

You want to use `scala.util.Using`, like for instance:

```scala
Using(new FileWriter(file)) { fileWriter =>
  // Use the fileWriter
  // No need to explicitly close it
  ???
} match {
  case Failure(_) => ???
  case Success(_) => ???
}
```

> A utility for performing automatic resource management. It can be used to perform an operation using resources, after which it releases the resources in reverse order of their creation.
>
> See [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Using$.html) (Scala 3 but applies to 2.13 as well).

If using Scala < 2.13, you can still use `Using` thanks to the (badly-named) https://github.com/scala/scala-collection-compat which backports `Using`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am on scala 2.12.

Comment: @Mandroid, see my update, it's available in 2.12 as well through a compat library